# SSAS new measure with a fixed dimension value

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a measure in SSAS 2012 that looks something like that in MDX:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[DWH FACT Events Count]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [27BI]
WHERE 
  [DWH DIM Event Name].[Event Name].&[wizard_done-button_click];
```

This gives me the result of counting rows (DWH FACT Events Count) when the Event Name is fixated to be "wizard_done-button_click".
I want this measure to update on each slice of the cube (i.e choose a country). While this query works, I don't know how to get it to become an actual measure.

One solution I saw was to create a Calculation:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[WizardDone]

AS 
  (
    [Measures].[DWH FACT Events Count] , 
    [DWH DIM Event Name].[Event Name].&[wizard_done-button_click]
  )
```

This calculated member gives me the result I want, but it doesn't update when I browse the cube and try to slice it by different dimensions.

Comment: Are your "different dimensions" related, in the Dimension Usage, to the Measure Group where [Measures].[DWH FACT Events Count] is in?

Comment: I see what you mean! I was trying to slice it by dimensions that are not connected to this measure group. This actually works, I was just one step away from the solution. Thanks @mxix

Comment: @user2618351 - I would recommend you answering this question yourself and marking that as an answer. Trust me, someone would bless you in future for that :)